# Nativescript Image-picker can't find files in external storage

Tags: angular, nativescript

I used nativescript-imagepicker ([related website](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-imagepicker)) and I implement all the things exactly as were in the document and sample codes.

I also set the permission code in the AndroidManifest.xml, that fixed for the API 29 and upper, but unfortunately I get this error after choosing a photo from the device gallery:

> **Asset 'content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/..._photos.jpg' cannot be found.**

Code:

```
let context = imagepicker.create({
  mode: "single"
});
context.authorize()
  .then(() => {
    return context.present();
  }).then(selection => {

    const imageAsset = selection.length > 0 ? selection[0] : null;
    imageAsset.options.height = 1024;
    imageAsset.options.width = 1024;
    imageAsset.options.keepAspectRatio = true;
    
    ImageSource.fromAsset(imageAsset).then((imageSource: ImageSource) => {
      this.defaultImage = "";
      this.changedImage = imageSource;
      this.uploadImage(imageSource);
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    })
  })
  .catch(function (e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" ... >
```

PS: someone has written that adding `compileSdkVersion = 29` to the **app.gradle** should fix it but that doesn't work!

Anyone can help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi I found your answer after a long time on search.imagepicker return image address in `content://` format so imagesource cant find out it.you must convert `content://` format to `file://` format.so change your code same below

```
let context = imagepicker.create({
      mode: "single"
    });
    context.authorize()
      .then(() => {
        return context.present();
      }).then(selection => {
        const imageAsset = selection.length > 0 ? selection[0] : null;
        imageAsset.options.height = 1024;
        imageAsset.options.width = 1024;
        imageAsset.options.keepAspectRatio = true;
        const source = new ImageSource();
        if (imageAsset.android) {
          //console.log(getPathFromUri(imageAsset.android));
          ImageSource.fromFile(getPathFromUri(imageAsset.android)).then((imageSource: ImageSource) => {
           this.defaultImage = "";
           this.changedImage = imageSource;
           this.uploadImage(imageSource);});
           //viewModel.uploadFile(file);   
       }else{
        source.fromAsset(imageAsset).then((imageSource: ImageSource) => {
          this.defaultImage = "";
          this.changedImage = imageSource;
          this.uploadImage(imageSource);
        })}
      }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
      });



 export function getPathFromUri(path) {
      let context=Utils.android.getApplicationContext();
      let uri = android.net.Uri.parse(path);
      let isKitKat = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 
 android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT;
      // DocumentProvider
     // if (isKitKat )
       {      
          // ExternalStorageProvider
          if (uri.getAuthority().includes("externalstorage")) {
              let docId = android.provider.DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
              let split = docId.split(":");
              let type:string = split[0];
              //System.out.println("getPath() docId: " + docId + ", split: " + split.length + ", type: " + type);
    
              // This is for checking Main Memory
              if ("primary"===type.toLocaleLowerCase()) {
                  if (split.length > 1) {
                      return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1] + "/";
                  } else {
                      return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/";
                  }
                  // This is for checking SD Card
              } else {
                  return "/storage/emulated/0" + "/" + docId.replace(":", "/");
              }
    
          }
      }
      return null;
    }
```